# RxJava .filter is blocking other code from sending data to API

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, jobs, evernote

I'm using RxJava inside an evernote job to send some data to API. This code was working just fine till now. The problem is somewhere in the `.filter` I think as it isn't even getting to `getApiService().createReport(requestModel)` method unless there are photos in the model (then the `report.getImages()` is not `null`.

```
    public static Observable<Report> createReport(CreateReportModel model) {
    return Observable.just(model)
            .filter(report -> report.getImages() != null)
            .flatMap(report -> {
                 return Observable.from(report.getImages())
                        .map(photoModel -> {
                            return photoModel;
                        })
                        .filter(photoModel -> photoModel.hasImage())
                        .filter(photoModel -> photoModel.getImage().exists())
                        .flatMap(photoModel -> uploadFile(photoModel)).toList();
            })
            .map(photoModels -> model)
            .flatMap(requestModel -> {
                return getApiService().createReport(requestModel)
                        .map(response -> {
                            return response;
                        });
            });
}
```

This function is called inside this code

```
Observable<PalletReport> report = createReport(model);
    report.subscribe(new Subscriber<PalletReport>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            resultHolder.setResult(Result.SUCCESS);

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Timber.d(e, "Upload Error");
            resultHolder.setResult(Result.RESCHEDULE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(PalletReport model) {
            Timber.d("On Next " + model);
        }

    });
```

And here it goes to `Result.SUCCESS` but the response isn't get and the report isn't create on back end. My concern is that this code was working just fine a few days ago, and without any changes it stopped.

[EDIT]

I have this function that is called inside the first flatMap, and it's used to send the photos.

```
@NonNull
private static Observable<? extends CreatePalletPhotoModel> uploadPalletFile(CreatePalletPhotoModel photo) {
    MultipartBody.Part fileBody = Paperless.createFileBody(photo.getImage());
    return Paperless.getApiService().uploadPalletPhoto(fileBody)
            .map(upload -> {
                photo.setPalletStatus(upload.getPalletStatus());
                photo.setImage(upload.getImage());
                return photo;
            });
}
```

Comment: so what exactly is not working? you are right in saying that api service will not be called if items are report is filtered out.

Comment: If there are no images then the first `.flatMap` should not execute (that's for sending the photos) but the second `.flatMap` is for sending the report and that should work (not it's not working). `return getApiService().createReport(requestModel)` is never called.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no reports after `filter` nothing will get executed. Consider removing

```
   .map(photoModels -> model)
```

and just end the first observable there (you would need to subscribe to it) and start again with

```
Observable.just(model).flatMap(requestModel -> {
            return getApiService().createReport(requestModel)
                    .map(response -> {
                        return response;
                    });
        });
```

that will ensure that `getApiService` call is always executed.

Comment: I'm kinda new to RxJava can you help me with the way to subscribe it and how will it work?

Comment: easiest is just to rewrite first block as a normal java for loop

Comment: I have edited the question. I don't understand. How can I rewrite the first block. And in the edit there is a function that for sending photos, where can I call that function. Please tell me more information as I don't quite understand what you want to tell. Thanks